# sort a jquery div based on one of the <p> (paragraph tags)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is the repetivite html structure that i have in my template:

```
<div class="mystyle" data-id= "11002">
  <div class="style1-header"><h6>Change Status of Task</h6></div>
  <p class="style1-content">Seriously Change Status of Task</p>
  <p class="style2-content" style="visibility:hidden">12</p>
</div>
```

The above is the html structure that keeps repeating in my html template. I wanted these things to be sorted based on the numbers `12` as in the above case. 
How can i do it with jquery. The [fiddle is available here.](http://jsfiddle.net/sJQCd/1/)

Comment: Do you have control over the HTML or is it locked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use JavaScript's `Array.sort` method to sort an array of the divs.

```
var $divs = $('div.mystyle').get().sort(function(a,b){
    var aKey = +$(a).find('p.style2-content').text(),
        bKey = +$(b).find('p.style2-content').text();
    return aKey - bKey;
});
```

Then append the now sorted array to the DOM.

```
$('body').append($divs);
```

Comment: I'm trying to get a fiddle of this running and it's not working. What am I missing?

Comment: @j08691: I forgot to add `.text()`.  Try it now.

Comment: Hmmm, the final sort ended up as 1, 8, 9, 12, 6, 3, 5, 2. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sJQCd/3/

Comment: @j08691: Some of the `<h6>`s were missing `</div>`s after them.  http://jsfiddle.net/sJQCd/4/

Comment: Maybe there is no need in `+`. It should work fine even without type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var $elements = $("div.mystyle");
 function sortFn(a, b) {
      var aText = $(a).find("p:hidden").text();
      var bText = $(a).find("p:hidden").text();
      return aText > bText ? 0 : 1;
 }

 $elements.sort(sortFn);
```

Comment: `sort` returns one of 3 values.  `-1` if `a < b`, `1` if `a > b`, or `0` if `a === b`.